# Why doesn't the exe file run while the solution itself in Visual Studio could run smoothly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, visual-c++

I'm trying to run the .exe file of my project in Visual Studio, on other systems that don't have Visual Studio installed, but the problem is that the solution can run when I click on "start" but when I run the .exe file the error "the code execution cannot proceed because mkl_tbb_thread.dll was not found...", I really cannot figure out how to deal with this, can anyone help me with this please?
I have tried some methods like changing the runtime library to static form and changing some other options but none of them actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the whole debug or release folder (or at least its content). The program is looking for some .dll you have added as reference in Visual Studio.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to run the .exe file on my own system first, but it doesn't run even on my system, let alone other systems.

Comment: Does mkl_tbb_thread.dll exist in the output folder? If not could you try copying it into the output folder?

Comment: No, it doesn't, the only file that I managed to find was mkl-tbb-thread-dll.lib, there was no .dll with such name, and I copied the mentioned file into the output file but nothing changed.

Comment: Well I found this article https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-compiling-and-linking-with-microsoft-visual-cc that may be relevant but otherwise I'm out of ideas

Comment: Programming questions are out of scope here at Superuser

Comment: I made an flag to migrate the question to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com but it was declined

Answer (score 0):

According to
[this article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-windows-developer-guide-contents-of-the-redist-intel64-win-mkl-directory),
the DLL `mkl_tbb_thread.dll` is part of
[Threading Building Blocks (Intel® TBB)](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/).

This package must be installed on the target, or you may include with your
program the contents of the folder `redist\intel64_win\mkl` that you will
find in its installation folder on your computer.

Comment: how should I install TBB? I couldn't find any explanation on installing it, and I have no idea how to use it, and there was no mkl_tbb_thread.dll in the files, would you please help me through this?

Comment: You don't to install it, just include the contents of the `redist` folder with your program in its folder.

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking a trivial question, but there is no redist folder among the TBB folders.

Comment: This [document](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506049) describes the folder as `..\redist\<arch>\tbb\vc<vcversion>\<lib><variant>.dll`. Accordingly, the `redist` folder should be outside of the TBB installation folder and have the same parent. Not very nice. Read carefully this link for the naming convention of the subfolder that you need to copy.